# Post a comment and like a news on a facebook fan page outside facebook

Tags: php, facebook, web

I retrieved my wall feed with php (without the sdk) and i got this below. Can i like the news and comment it via my website and not via facebook ?

does the comment ant the like can be differents ?

```
[0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Comment
                                    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/143788389048247/posts/143799919047094
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Like
                                    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/143788389048247/posts/143799919047094
                                )
```

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 143788389048247_143799919047094
                    [from] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => Dirtier than.
                            [category] => Cause
                            [id] => 143788389048247
                        )

                    [message] => The first quote of this page
"Dirtier than Ron Jeremy's Browser History"
                    [actions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Comment
                                    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/143788389048247/posts/143799919047094
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [name] => Like
                                    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/143788389048247/posts/143799919047094
                                )

                        )

                    [privacy] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [description] => Public
                            [value] => EVERYONE
                        )

                    [type] => status
                    [created_time] => 2011-09-02T16:33:01+0000
                    [updated_time] => 2011-09-02T16:33:01+0000
                    [comments] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                    [is_published] => 1
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can you just need to post a like or comment to facebook

check this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Thank you ! Sometimes its just difficult to search for exact good things.